# Losing data in Vagrant after restart or destroy

Tags: mysql, database, vagrant

I am new to Vagrant and have a couple of questions.

Sometimes when I restart my computer or destroy my vagrant the whole MySQL database is wiped out.
I tried to find some answers about this on stackoverflow but didn't have any luck so far.

So my questions are:

1) Where does the data get stored?

2) Why do I sometimes lose data?

3) If so how do I keep the data after restart of destroy?

Comment: `destroy` [*removes all traces of the virtual machine from the corresponding provider*](https://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/cli/destroy.html). It's not very surprising that this includes your data. If you want to shut down the VM without losing data, use `halt` or `suspend`.

Comment: To me it doesn't make sense why it also removes the database. I know it will remove all the vagrant traces but why database? Where does this get stored? Why does it wipe out the database sometimes when I restart and not always?

Comment: host the DB outside of vagrant

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In my opinion, the answers to your questions depend on how you set up the project. On a project that I work on our set up is the following (simplified):

- database server (cloud hosted)
- origin server (cloud hosted)
- vagrant box for local development
- git repository
- ...

On `vagrant init` each developer gets a copy of the environment which is a ubuntu server. All application code (website) is mounted into the virtual machine from your local file system. We keep this application in the git repository. Then we keep a few scripts inside the vagrant machine that synchronize the database from the production (or demo server) - basically it downloads the database dump file and places it into your virtual machine.

In that case, if you do `vagrant destroy` and then `vagrant init` you need to run the database sync script to get the databse back. Our developers (mostly) don't change the content of the database so we don't need to keep the local changes.

I hope that this helps a bit.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Is it best practice to use an online database compared to a local db in vagrant? Also where are the db files stored?

Comment: I think that you probably want to have a local database in your virtual machine. The description above comes from a web application project which uses a centralized database. Vagrant provisions a local copy of that database so that a developer can work in a sandboxed environment. If you are developing a desktop software using a database then you may not need an online database. But that will vary on the requirements. It seems that you run the database server inside the virtual machine so depending on what that system is the path will vary. E.g. MySQL db on Ubuntu could be in /var/lib/mysql/

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/installation-layouts.html this may explain the location of installed MySQL files if that's what you were asking.

Comment: Thanks I will look this up. I appreciate the information you have given me!

Answer (score 2):

*The top answer is pretty good, I just wanted to add to your third question.*

To keep your changes, you should **keep the database on your host machine**, and have vagrant connect to it to use it. This way you won't lose the database on **vagrant destroy**.

You're probably already using NFS to sync the folders with the code, so this is just a step in a similar direction.

Comment: Can you link anything about it?

Comment: @alayli I don't have a link, since I ended up rolling my own solution. But what you basically do is have the code within Vagrant connect to the database on your host machine. 

To do this you're going to have to know the IP address of the host machine from within Vagrant, and you might have to tweak the database on the host to allow remote connections from the Vagrant IP.

Answer (score 1):

Homestead already added DB Backup feature, If you have Vagrant 2.1.0 or above than all you have to do is add this to `Homestead.yaml`

```
backup: true
```

Once configured, Homestead will export your databases to mysql_backup and postgres_backup directories when the vagrant destroy command is executed.
[Readmore](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/homestead#database-backups)

Answer (score 0):

Another solution for question 3 that I recently used is to install the [vagrant-triggers](https://github.com/emyl/vagrant-triggers) plugin:

```
vagrant plugin install vagrant-triggers
```

Then add some code to the `Vagrantfile` to run a script on `halt` and `destroy`:

```
config.trigger.before :halt do
  info "Backing up databases"
  run_remote  "bash /vagrant/backup_databases.sh"
end

config.trigger.before :destroy do
  info "Backing up databases"
  run_remote  "bash /vagrant/backup_databases.sh"
end
```

Then create the `backup_databases.sh` script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

BACKUP_DIR="/vagrant/database_backups"

mysqldump -u root databasename > "$BACKUP_DIR/$(date +%Y-%m-%d_%H:%M).databasename.sql"
mysqldump -u root databasename2 > "$BACKUP_DIR/$(date +%Y-%m-%d_%H:%M).databasename2.sql"

# remove all but the 10 most recent backups
cd $BACKUP_DIR
ls -t | sed -e '1,10d' | xargs -r -d '\n' rm
```

My `database_backups` folder is not versioned and won't disappear if my vagrant box is destroyed. This setup allows me to have recent backups in my local environment that I can restore any time I want.

This is less useful when working with large databases, though. In those situations I prefer Nick Zinger's answer of keeping the database on the host machine and connecting to it from within vagrant.